# zoom a sprite in andengine (Android)

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I want my sprite (sprite has dynamic body) to zoom-in or zoom-out smoothly, let's say when I click this sprite. i tried to use EntitiyModifier and ScaleModofier in it. Below is the code I used:

```
SequenceEntityModifier seq_zoom = new SequenceEntityModifier(
            new ScaleModifier(4f, 1f, 0.454545f));
........
mMySprite.registerEntityModifier(seq_zoom); // On Clicking the sprite
```

But nothing happens to the sprite. Can anyone guide me, on how to apply smooth zooming on a sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you are doing is enlarging the sprite, it does not zoom on it (Rest of the scene stays the same size and scaling).

You can use the [SmoothCamera](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/engine/camera/SmoothCamera.java), you can see an example [here](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/ZoomExample.java). I think its better than scaling (even though it does the same..)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I link smooth camera with just a single sprite of the scene. Whereas all rest of the scene remains the same.